# How to set the windows "Read & Execute" permisson flag with Ant?

Tags: windows, ant, chmod

I need to set the "Read & Execute" flag for a file. Since Ant's [chmod task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/chmod.html) can't do this, is there another way to do it with Ant? Maybe using [Exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) and use the windows specific command?

**EDIT:**

I need to set the "Read & execute" flag, you can see on the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: NTFS doesn't have execute file attribute.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Ok, thanks. I'm not sure about the filesystem, so I removed that. Instead I added a screenshot, showing the actual permission flags.

Answer (score 1):

[`attrib`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/attrib.html) is probably what you're looking for. It uses the [`attrib`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true) windows command behind the scenes.

Comment: That is because it is not a flag like on *nix systems.  It is a permission given to a user or group.

Answer (score 1):

To set the security properties for an object, you can use [icacls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Good pointer thanks, but unfortunately the Ant task is mostly executed on Windows XP. I found cacls.exe but it doesn't contain the execute option.